# "The type name SqlConnection could not be found in the namespace 'System..Data.SqlClient' Error message

Tags: sql

Could anybody help me with this error? it doesnt tell me what's wrong, neither do google results.[image]

Comment: This isn't really related to the <sql> _language_. Which api/environment/etc is it?

Comment: You've neglected to add the `System.Data.SqlClient` package to your project. Though you probably want to switch to `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` anyway.